# NightMode toggle button state in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toggle, android-night-mode

I am working with a third party library in android studio.

github link: https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Night-Mode-Button

The Night mode toggle button is working fine.

I want to save its State even after the App is closed.

The `toggle.setChecked(false);` is not working in this case as a result of which we cannot use shared preferences

how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of the `Night-Mode-Button`, you could use the `OnSwitchListener` like so to save the state of the button:

```
nightModeButton.setOnSwitchListener(new NightModeButton.OnSwitchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSwitchListener(boolean isNight) {
        // Store the boolean in SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.APP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("NightMode", isNight);
    });
}
```

However, from the [issues on the GitHub page](https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Night-Mode-Button/issues/2), it looks like more people are facing the issue you raised about not being able to set the button's state, and it also looks like there is no solution for it yet.

So: saving the button's state can be done through the `OnSwitchListener`, but setting the button's state seems to not be possible with this library as of now.

Comment: ok Sir,is there any other better library which can be used to make night mode toggle

Comment: I would suggest using a normal Switch for adjusting to night mode, the following tutorial explains this step by step: https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode .